# Priority Queue without thread-safeness

Tags: python

I'm currently using Queue.PriorityQueue in my program.
However, 20% of the total running time in my program is used for all the locks and notifies to keep the queue thread-safe.

Is there a priority queue in python 2.7 which is optimized for one thread?

**edit:** Verified that it is indeed the threading which drags down performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [heapq](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)?  It seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: I'm adding a bunch of tuples to the PQ, and as I understood heapq uses __cmp__, which I can't overload in a tuple. Also, heapq seems a bit lower level than PQ, and might be used if you are implementing your own priority queue.

Comment: My current solution is to just copy the Queue.py from the standard library and force it to use the dummy_threading, which works, but it's not nice.

Comment: @MarcusJohansson: Queue.PriorityQueue uses the exact same comparison methods as heapq. In fact, Queue.PriorityQueue just delegates to heapq. heapq is exactly what you want.